# SQL Server ASYNC_IO_NETWORK wait time for local BCP

Tags: sql-server

This is my first ever question on dba.stackexchange.  I am an experienced DBA, and I just changed company.

My problem:  On any SQLServer in this new shoppe, I find the output times really slow.  I mean, I am on the local machine, I bcp a table that *I have checked* is fully loaded into the buffer pool (physical reads = 0) into a local file, and I barely hit 30 Mb/s into the loading of the file.  The query is a Select * from table.  The table is 5.7GB big, totally 15 million lines.  With SSMS, of course it is way slower.  The problem is not BCP or SSMS, the problem is I find that output really slow compared to the beast I have as a server.  My storage is capped at around 300Mo/s - but in this case it is only really used by the output file as the table datapages are cached.

When I check wait times, of course my main wait type is ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, which was pretty predictible, since it is only scrolling throught the pages in memory and shouting them out to the client.  **What is *NOT* normal in my opinion, is to have 75% of the total elapsed time which consists of waiting for the client.  The client being a local BCP,** I expected to hit a way bigger throuput.

It is SQLServer 2019, patched to CU 18, on a Win2019 server VM, hosted on a VMWare Esxi 7. [EDIT ADD] 16 CPUs, 84GB RAM.  Min & Max server memory are properly set, lock pages in memory as well.  I don't see anything odd or funny in the SQL configuration, even though I have been installing SQLServers since version 7 (4cds version)... [/EDIT]

Some details & tests I did:

1. Inserting the table into a #tmp table -> 6 seconds elasped, it goes parallel.  Selecting the #tmp table in local SSMS takes forever (30s per million) and does not go parallel.
2. Same test as 1, but on my SSD laptop, with a quick and dirty developper edt install and a restore from the same DB on the laptop and running the same BCP query on it:  Inserting into #tmp takes double the time (12 seconds), but selecting takes half as long!  BCP goes twice as fast on my laptop, even though SQLServer can't cache the whole table due to memory pressure.

What do you guys think?

1. Do you think those times are abnormal like me or not?
2. Do you know any way to tweak the output buffer ?  I know how to look at it, DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER (session_id), but I know no way of making it go faster.

Thank you guys, don't hesitate if you need any more information.

EDIT:  I did some VMWare checks and everything looks right, no ballooning, the resources are reserved everywhere (cpu, ram and disk are not overallocated and have priorities set for the server).  Storage tests of file copies show 300Mb/s copy rates.
Another important piece of news:  backups are made to the storage speed, over 200MB/s.

EDIT: Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OERS](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [IDReio] [int] NULL,
    [Datebegin] [date] NULL,
    [Dateend] [date] NULL,
    [IDProduct] [bigint] NULL,
    [IDjiu] [int] NULL,
    [CodePrice] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Price] [numeric](16, 9) NULL,
    [min] [numeric](16, 9) NULL,
    [IDpkny] [int] NULL,
    [IDpknyo] [bigint] NULL,
    [IDRaze] [bigint] NULL,
    [CodeRaze] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Codepkny] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [IDTi] [int] NULL,
    [CodeTi] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [IDGrTi] [int] NULL,
    [CodeGrpTi] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CodexOP] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ProductR4Px] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rownum] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Deleted] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [offerNoTag] [bit] NULL,
    [PrixA] [numeric](16, 9) NULL,
    [IDTA] [int] NULL,
    [online] [bit] NULL,
    [Qite] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [is_available] [bit] NULL,
    [dlvr_start_date] [date] NULL,
    [x_end_date] [date] NULL,
    [x_day] [bigint] NULL,
    [x_fran] [bit] NULL,
    [qity_increment] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
    [x_offline] [bit] NULL,
    [x_type] [int] NULL,
    [x_supplier_reference] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [x_qy] [decimal](10, 3) NULL,
    [x_qy_warehouse] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [x_qy_company] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [x_qy_max_warehouse] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [x_o_type] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [x_IDProductle] [int] NULL,
    [x_UUIDProduitModele] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [x_UUIDProduct] [varchar](36) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

BCP command:

```
BCP DB.dbo.oers out v:\BCP\BCP_export.txt -T SMyMachine\MyInstance -c
```

I tried to changed block size for a negligible gain (up to -a 32765, over that it stays at this value).
It goes around 30% faster in native (-n) as opposed to -c.

But again, the goal is not to make BCP go faster, I just use it to get a reasonably fast client to make the problem appear in full.

I also tried a few things regarding to network, like changing to IP connection, activating and deactivating shared memory, to no avail.

[EDIT] CrystalDiskMark Logs

All tests are on 4GB file size.

For TempDB drive:

```
[Read]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   468.702 MB/s [    447.0 IOPS] < 17858.99 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   375.410 MB/s [    358.0 IOPS] <  2790.82 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   277.995 MB/s [  67869.9 IOPS] <   471.05 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    26.057 MB/s [   6361.6 IOPS] <   156.77 us>

[Write]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   454.628 MB/s [    433.6 IOPS] < 18359.41 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   316.649 MB/s [    302.0 IOPS] <  3307.75 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   105.947 MB/s [  25866.0 IOPS] <  1235.40 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):     8.168 MB/s [   1994.1 IOPS] <   500.34 us>
```

For the SQLServer binaries & system DBs:

```
[Read]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   445.932 MB/s [    425.3 IOPS] < 18767.37 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   355.461 MB/s [    339.0 IOPS] <  2947.26 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   266.955 MB/s [  65174.6 IOPS] <   490.53 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    21.148 MB/s [   5163.1 IOPS] <   193.24 us>

[Write]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   373.743 MB/s [    356.4 IOPS] < 22318.30 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   262.976 MB/s [    250.8 IOPS] <  3981.13 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):    92.627 MB/s [  22614.0 IOPS] <  1413.03 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):     8.627 MB/s [   2106.2 IOPS] <   473.77 us>
```

For the DB MDF &log drive (DB in simple recovery model):

```
[Read]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   453.642 MB/s [    432.6 IOPS] < 18441.01 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   326.284 MB/s [    311.2 IOPS] <  3211.51 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   273.126 MB/s [  66681.2 IOPS] <   479.42 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):    25.585 MB/s [   6246.3 IOPS] <   159.63 us>

[Write]
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  8, T= 1):   451.667 MB/s [    430.7 IOPS] < 18484.86 us>
  SEQ    1MiB (Q=  1, T= 1):   304.498 MB/s [    290.4 IOPS] <  3436.18 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q= 32, T= 1):   109.393 MB/s [  26707.3 IOPS] <  1196.74 us>
  RND    4KiB (Q=  1, T= 1):     7.529 MB/s [   1838.1 IOPS] <   542.39 us>
```

Comment: I keep thinking that it's disk I/O.  Try outputting to a file that's on the same drive/lun as your tempDB and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I put TempdB on a ramdisk that outputed in the 10GB/s, with no luck whatsoever.  Moreover, I would not understand the physical reads =0 , it may be tempdb, it's STILL a physical read if it has to hit the disk for a page that is not in the buffer pool, no?

Comment: Please provide the full BCP command you’re using, and table definition.

Comment: Edited with your demands.  Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Perhaps if you ran `bcp` with the `out` to NUL, you could determine whether it's the disk that is slow, or just `bcp` talking to the server...

Comment: You are running the command localy on laptop against a remote server? I don't think this is clear from your post

Comment: What does [Crystal Disk Mark](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/) have to say about the drives involved, both where the database files live and the destination of the BCP command?

Comment: @mustaccio:  did your test, exact same speed, only thing slowing it down now is the bcp output itself.

Comment: @rois . Indeed, going to clarify that: I have installed SQLServer on my laptop and restored the exact same DB on it through backup and that's it.  Then I threw the bcp command at my laptop from itself just like I did with the server  and boum, twice as fast as production server.

Comment: @YADBA cool, so what does Crystal Disk Mark say for all the disks involved with your use case in production? FWIW, 300 MB/s isn't exactly fast but 30 MB/s is obviously a problem.

Comment: @J.D. I'll put that up as soon as I can, probably tomorrow, I need to talk to the infra dudes about that first to spot the quietest time possible (benchmarking on a h24 production server)...  Yeah 300Mb/s I have seen better as well, but this is a "little" shop (DBA scale wise), if I can get to that through SQLServer selects that would already x10 what is happening now.

Comment: @YADBA Sounds good, I was originally confused as I thought your reply to Rois was directed at me. I'm on board now.

Comment: @J.D. Posted the CrystalDiskMark logs.  Thank you.